# Ajax Success function working only in debug

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this javascript function calling ajax, the success function windows location only work when I debug the codes and add a breakpoint in the chrome debugger. I have removed console.log and also tried location.assign and location.reload but it still does not work. I am not very experience in javascript and ajax, and need some guidance for this codes.

```
function changeFormAction() {
        var array = [];
        var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
          array.push(checkboxes[i].value);
        };
        let longurl =  "http://123.com/cart" + array ;
            var url = longurl;
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url:url,
                    async: true,
                    cache:false,
                    success: function(){
                        window.location.href = "http://123.com/checkout";
                    }
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors instead of `type` use `method`. `$.ajax` is jQuery syntax so you may use jQuery. Here as you expect (Use your own URL),

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Jquery</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick='changeFormAction()'>Click me</button>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function changeFormAction() {
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
    success: function(){
       window.location.href = "http://123.com/checkout";
     }
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```